# Meaning of AbstractPackageSanityTests exceptions in Guava testlib

Tags: java, guava, guava-testlib

I'm using Guava Testlib's [`AbstractPackageSanityTests`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/AbstractPackageSanityTests.java) and I just don't understand the exceptions I get. So what do they mean? And what do I need to change to fix those?

This is my test class:

```
package be.fror.racetrack;

import com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests;

public class PackageSanityTests extends AbstractPackageSanityTests {
  public PackageSanityTests() {
    publicApiOnly();
  }
}
```

And these are the errors I get when I run the test case.

```
Running be.fror.racetrack.PackageSanityTests
Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.21 sec <<< FAILURE!
testNulls(be.fror.racetrack.PackageSanityTests)  Time elapsed: 0.554 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Error in automated nulls test of class be.fror.racetrack.Racer
If the class is better tested explicitly, you can add testNulls() to be.fror.racetrack.RacerTest
    at com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests.sanityError(AbstractPackageSanityTests.java:288)
    at com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests.testNulls(AbstractPackageSanityTests.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Can't find or create a sample instance for type 'be.fror.racetrack.Vector'; please provide one using NullPointerTester.setDefault()
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
    at com.google.common.testing.NullPointerTester.buildParamList(NullPointerTester.java:365)
    at com.google.common.testing.NullPointerTester.testParameter(NullPointerTester.java:336)
    at com.google.common.testing.NullPointerTester.testMethodParameter(NullPointerTester.java:210)
    at com.google.common.testing.NullPointerTester.testMethod(NullPointerTester.java:178)
    at com.google.common.testing.NullPointerTester.testStaticMethods(NullPointerTester.java:124)
    at com.google.common.testing.ClassSanityTester.doTestNulls(ClassSanityTester.java:227)
    at com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests.testNulls(AbstractPackageSanityTests.java:213)
    ... 25 more

testEquals(be.fror.racetrack.PackageSanityTests)  Time elapsed: 0.127 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Error in automated equals test of class be.fror.racetrack.Racer
If the class is better tested explicitly, you can add testEquals() to be.fror.racetrack.RacerTest
    at com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests.sanityError(AbstractPackageSanityTests.java:288)
    at com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests.testEquals(AbstractPackageSanityTests.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: com.google.common.testing.ClassSanityTester$ParameterNotInstantiableException: Cannot determine value for parameter be.fror.racetrack.Vector arg1 of be.fror.racetrack.Racer.public static be.fror.racetrack.Racer be.fror.racetrack.Racer.startingAtWithVelocity(be.fror.racetrack.Player,be.fror.racetrack.Vector,be.fror.racetrack.Vector)
    at com.google.common.testing.ClassSanityTester.generateDummyArg(ClassSanityTester.java:672)
    at com.google.common.testing.ClassSanityTester.testEqualsUsing(ClassSanityTester.java:581)
    at com.google.common.testing.ClassSanityTester.doTestEquals(ClassSanityTester.java:323)
    at com.google.common.testing.AbstractPackageSanityTests.testEquals(AbstractPackageSanityTests.java:249)
    ... 25 more
```

Since these exceptions mention `Racer` and `Vector`, here are they:

`Vector.java` (there is no `VectorTest.java` yet):

```
package be.fror.racetrack;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class Vector {
  // Factory methods
  public static Vector zero() { return new Vector(0, 0); }
  public static Vector of(int x, int y) { return new Vector(x, y); }
  public static Vector copyOf(Vector other) {
    if (other == null) { throw new NullPointerException(); }
    // Vector is immutable. Don't make unuseful copies.
    return other;
  }

  // Data
  private final int x;
  private final int y;
  private Vector(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
  public int getX() { return x; }
  public int getY() { return y; }

  // Business
  public Vector add(Vector other) { return of(x + other.x, y + other.y); }

  // Overriding Object
  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Vector) {
      Vector other = (Vector) obj;
      return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
    return false;
  }
  @Override public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(x, y); }
  @Override public String toString() { return String.format("(%d,%d)", x, y); }
}
```

`Racer.java` (there is no `RacerTest.java` yet):

```
package be.fror.racetrack;

/**
 *
 * @author Olivier Grégoire
 */
public final class Racer {
  // Factory methods
  public static Racer startingAt(Player player, Vector position) { return startingAtWithVelocity(player, position, Vector.zero()); }
  public static Racer startingAtWithVelocity(Player player, Vector position, Vector velocity) {
    if (player == null || position == null || velocity == null) { throw new NullPointerException();}
    return new Racer(player, position, velocity);
  }

  // Data
  private final Player player;
  private Vector position;
  private Vector velocity;
  private Racer(Player player, Vector position, Vector velocity) {
    this.player = player;
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
  }
  public Player getPlayer() { return player; }
  public Vector getPosition() { return position; }
  public Vector getVelocity() { return velocity; }

  public void accelerateAndMove(Direction direction) {
    velocity = velocity.add(direction.asVector());
    position = position.add(velocity);
  }

  // Overriding Object
  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Racer) { return super.equals(obj); }
    return false;
  }
  @Override public int hashCode() { return super.hashCode(); }
  @Override public String toString() { return String.format("Racer{position=%s, velocity=%s}", position, velocity); }
}
```

Comment: The tester is trying to reflectively create instances of the classes, but can't since there is no default constructor. If you provide a factory, e.g. `setDefault(Vector.class, Vector.zero())` then it should work.

Comment: @BenManes This explains the first issue (but not the second), thanks. But now that I've added your suggestion, the test now says it expects a `NullPointerException` to be thrown by `Racer.equals(Object)`. Really? Is guava-testlib even stable? I wish there was some documentation at least... I created [an issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2128) in that regard.

Comment: Well, the first issue is totally resolved now, thanks to adding `@Nullable` to the parameter of `equals`.

Comment: With `setDefault` and `@Nullable`, are you still seeing failures? Sorry that the docs aren't much help here :(

Comment: @ChrisPovirk The first error is totally resolved with both `setDefault` and `@Nullable` (I had to read the source code to find out the nullable rule, hence the creation of the ticket above-mentioned). However... I still saw a failure for the second error. I ended up writing my own `RacerTest::testEquals` test case, but I'm sure it's much less covered than what guava-testlib can do. And I'm also sure there's a *real* way to fix this rather than writing my own test-case, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `testEquals` problem, the "right" solution is probably for your `PackageSanityTests()` constructor to call `setDistinctValues(Vector.class, Vector.zero(), Vector.of(1, 1))`.

The idea here is that, in order to test `Racer.equals()`, the tests need to create an instance of `Racer`. To create an instance, they need to call one of the static factory methods on `Racer`. To do that, they need, among other things, a `Vector` -- two distinct `Vector` objects, no less. But although the tests were smart enough to look for a static factory method on `Racer`, they aren't smart enough to look for one on `Vector`.

I *think* that's it, anyway. There are enough layers of magic here that I may be remembering wrong.

Comment: Indeed, after testing, it proved successful. Thank you!